# How to use the proxy provided in .condarc for pip packages in the environment.yml?

Tags: python, proxy, pip, conda, requirements

I have to use a proxy, which I have configured in the .condarc file, for conda work, which works perfectly fine. However when I'm setting up a new python environment with an environment.yml file, which could look like this:

```
name: Test
channels:
  - intel
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pypdf2=1.26.0=py36_1
  - mkl=2018.0.2=1
  - pip:
    - adjusttext==0.7.2
prefix: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test
```

Pip doesn't use the provided proxy to install those packages, so I get an error. How can I get pip to use that proxy as well?

Comment: Same issue here. Any solution/workaround? @r-ghazaleh

Comment: It is fairly easy to upload pip packages to Anaconda Cloud. So I asked the developer of the pip package to host to Anaconda Cloud as well.
However I couldn't solve my original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed pip doesn't pick proxy settings from .condarc.
But it will use HTTPS_PROXY environment variable if present.
Just add this line to .bash_profile:
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://user:pwd@proxy_host:port

Answer (score 2):

Struggled with this issue a lot working on Win10. When modifying `https_proxy` I had issues with git, but with a file `pip.ini` in `C:\ProgramData\pip\` as `C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini` it works finally:

`pip.ini`:

```
[global]
timeout = 10
proxy=http://myproxy:8080
cert = C:\Users\Public\mycert.cer
```

now I can install conda environments with included pip packages

for more infos for default location visit: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/